# A generic error occurred in GDI+, Base64 Data To Image

Tags: c#

I have method like this,

```
public static void Base64ToImageAndSave(string rawData, string path)
        {
            string parsedData;

            parsedData = rawData.Contains(',')
                ? rawData.Substring(rawData.IndexOf(',') + 1)
                : rawData;

            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(parsedData);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                using (Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
                {
                    image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }

        }
```

I send base64 parameter for save the picture as a jpeg file. But I have this error

```
A generic error occurred in GDI+
```

on this line,

```
image.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I use using for dispose, but still have error. How can i solve this problem? thanks.

Comment: What is the value for `parsedData`? Can you create a reproducible piece of code?

Comment: you need a permission for the path you are trying to save.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866603/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-when-attempting-to-use-image-save.

Comment: My parsedData is `data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA.....`

Comment: do you have a full permission to the path you are trying to save?

Comment: Thanks all, it's about permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference:

If you are getting the same error , then we can say that you don't have a write permission on some directory.

For example, if you are trying to save the Image from the memory stream to the file system , you may get that error. 
Make sure to add write permission in folder or for the network service account.

Hope this helps!