# how to save file in c# hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hosting

how to save file using c# and hosting service inside "images" folder

i already tried 
code.Paint().Save("c:\image.png", ImageFormat.Png); and suceeded, but only at my local computer, after i uploading to some hosting account ( godaddy ) its not working
i already tried @"images\image.png" and ..\images\image.png and ~\images\image.png
and the error is A generic error occurred in GDI+.

```
FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"images\image.png", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

and still cannot, is that possible to dynamically add file to a hosting?
and after I save it, how to open it if I'm using picture box?
thanks

Comment: i think you have give folder  permission in hosting control pannel.

Comment: i already give full acess, but still can't, as i know, there no C;// path on hosting, so there's my problem

Comment: Is it the hosting computer you want to save the file on - or the local computer?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866603/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-when-attempting-to-use-image-save and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862810/a-generic-error-occured-in-gdi-in-bitmap-save-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx
i have successfully saving my file to my hosting 
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../images/image.png"),ImageFormat.Png;

Answer (score 1):

Try code as below,

FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("~/images/image.png", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

I hope this may solve your problem

Comment: sorry for late reply, still cannot, Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\~\images\images.png'.

Comment: Try this,
FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("../images/image.png", IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

Comment: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\images\image.png'.