# Can't retrieve image in SharpDevelop from an Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, picturebox, sharpdevelop

I was trying to upload and then see an image, saving it in a MS Access database.

I configure the column as "Long text" in Access for saving the bytes image.

This is the code that saves my image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pb_Imagen.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] aByte = ms.ToArray();
        
OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source = d:\\Archivos\\Descargas\\FastCare(1)\\Base de Datos\\Usuarios.accdb");
string comandSQL = "INSERT INTO Trabajadores (Nombre, Telefono, Rut, Email, Edad, Sexo, Estudios, Descripcion, Experiencia, Niños, Adultos, Imagen) VALUES ('"+_Nombre+"' , '"+_Telefono+"' , '"+_Rut+"', '"+_Email+"', '"+_Edad+"', '"+_Sexo+"', '"+_Estudios+"', '"+_Descripcion+"', '"+_Experiencia+"', '"+_Ninos+"', '"+_Adultos+"', @imagen)";
        
try
{
    MyConnection.Open();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return "No se puede conectar con la Base de Datos"+ex.Message;
}

OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand CommandQuery = new OleDbCommand(comandSQL, MyConnection);
CommandQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imagen", aByte);

try
{
    adapter.InsertCommand = CommandQuery;
    adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    return "Tu perfil como trabajador/a se registró correctamente";     
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return "No se pudo registrar, intente nuevamente"+ex.Message;   
}
```

This is the code to retrieve the image:

```
OleDbCommand consulta = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Trabajadores WHERE Nombre='"+cmb_Nombre.Text+"'");
            AbrirConexion();
            consulta.Connection = conexion;

OleDbDataReader leer = consulta.ExecuteReader();
            
if (leer.HasRows)
{
    leer.Read();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])leer["Imagen"]);
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
    pb_Imagen.Image = bm;
}   
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No se encontraron registros");
}
```

When I upload an image, I get no error message, but when I want to see the picture associated with "Nombre", I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte []'.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612039/why-is-my-image-from-database-not-displaying-properly-in-my-picturebox/66616751#66616751

Comment: Thanks! te problem wasn´t the code, the problem was in the data type on access. i change it from "Long text" to "OLE" and works nice.