# What may I do to display an image from the database to my picture box?

Tags: c#, image, display, picturebox

My table as 10 text fields and one picture box, I've failed to display the picture from the database to the picture box.

[Screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXFBc.png)[screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pgq6.png)

Comment: In future please post your actual code, and not a screenshot! That makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: I’d also recommend using parameters rather than building the SQL as it makes SQL injection impossible, as well as being a lot more readable and reliable

Comment: Finally, some of the objects you used should be disposed at the end of the method - the SqlCommand and the DataAdapter. You can do this manually by calling `.Dispose()` or wrap the objects in a `using` statement.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616751/10024425