# VB.Net Exporting SQL Server Varbinary Data Issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to export varbinary data from an SQL Server table and save it to disk. I can export it using a T-SQL script, but when I try to use VB.NET code, the application adds junk characters to the front and end of the file.

For the T-SQL I am using the following script:

```
EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; -- An instance created
  EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;  
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @VarBinaryData; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @FilePath, 2; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; -- Calling a method
  EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; -- Closed the resources
```

For the VB.NET code, I am using:

```
Dim _MemoryStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
Dim _BinaryFormatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
_BinaryFormatter.Serialize(_MemoryStream, aRow("VarBinaryData"))
_MemoryStream.ToArray()

File.WriteAllBytes("C:\Temp\NG Annotation\" + aRow("page_id").ToString() + ".art", _MemoryStream.ToArray())
```

When using the SQL code, the file looks like this

[image: Good Image Begin]

[image: Good Image End]

This is the Bad File (I highlighted the extra characters)

[image: Bad Image Begin]

[image: Bad Image End]

How can I keep the VB code from adding the extra characters?

Comment: Please provide the _VB.NET_ code used to both save and retrieve the _varbinary_ data from the database.

Comment: Offhand, since you are serializing your data with a binary formatter, you likely should also deserialize it with a binary formatter (to get back the original data).

Comment: I am not saving to the database. The data is saved from another application.

Comment: You're saving a serialized version of binary array, which adds header etc, that's not the same as the raw bytes. Why not just get the binary data from the row and save it directly

Comment: You should check the code from the other app so that you can see what acrionqlly was saved and revers it

Comment: What is `aRow("VarBinaryData")`?  It's probably already a `byte[]`.

Comment: I guess the *real* question is what on earth you are trying to do, and why you are using `sp_OA` procedures to do it, and in VB why you think you need `BianryFormatter`. To export from SQL Server you should use `bcp.exe` or similar. For VB.NET you already have a `byte[]` array, there is no need to format it. Just write the whole thing to disk. `File.WriteAllBytes(somepath, yourArray)`

Comment: For _varbinary_ data the following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66616751/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70321177/10024425

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to introduce serialization here.

To save a raw binary file into a row in SQL server, then this code:

```
    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)

        Dim strSQL As String =
            "INSERT INTO MyFiles (Filename, BFile)
            VALUES (@FileName, @BFILE)"

        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)

            Dim bFile As Byte()
            bFile = File.ReadAllBytes(txtFromFile.Text)

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFromFile.Text
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@BFILE", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bFile
            con.Open()
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cmdSQL.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY"
            txtID.Text = cmdSQL.ExecuteScalar  ' put new PK id in text box

        End Using

    End Using
```

To get and save the raw binary file from the database, then this code can be used:

```
    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT ID, BFile FROM MyFiles WHERE ID = @ID"
    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtID.Text
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using

    Dim bFile As Byte() = rstData.Rows(0)("Bfile")

    File.WriteAllBytes(txtSaveFile.Text, bFile)
```

So, note how we pull the column data into a byte array, and then write/save that to disk.