Load picture from SQL and set it as a picturebox image in C#
I am using this code to load an image from SQL and set it as a picturebox image. but the code does not work. I use "image"/"varbinary(Max)" for Logo image in SQL Server.
byte[] data = (byte[])(DT.Rows[0][18]);
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mem);

Actually, the last line show error:

Parameter is not valid

this is the way I send the picture to SQL ((object)imageData is the data that I send).
Image img = Image.FromFile(opf.FileName);
MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
img.Save(tmpStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); // change to other format
tmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
byte[] imageData = new byte[img.Size.Height * img.Height];
tmpStream.Read(imageData, 0, img.Size.Height * img.Height);


"I use "image"/"varbinary(Max)"" younreally should not be using the image data type in SQL Server anymore; that was deprecated way back in 2005.

Please tell us the full error, verbatim, not a summarised version. And have you confirmed that the correct data is being stored in your database? We can't do that for you.

Use the field name rather than an index when reading the column. Is the 19th field (index 18) the one which contains the image ?

Post the actual full exception text. Parameter is not valid isn't an exception, it's just the message part of the exception. If you load only one row at a time it's a lot faster to avoid DataTable and use SqlDataReader.GetStream to read the data directly into the image

When saving the image data, call ToArray on the MemoryStream to get the byte array. That should replace the last three lines. You may actually not be saving all the data.

Thanks to all for responding me,
As I wrote, (object)imageData was the data that I sent to sql server.
I changed it to (Array)imageData and the problem was solved.

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612039/why-is-my-image-from-database-not-displaying-properly-in-my-picturebox/66616751#66616751

Thanks to all for responding me, As I wrote, (object)imageData was the data that I sent to SQL Server. I changed it to (Array)imageData and the problem was solved.
