# Why can't I save "some" images from my pictureBox to the database?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, localdb

This is how I save my image(bytes) to my database and it works fine with insert and update operations:

```
public static byte[] ImageToBytes(Image userImage)//Get bytes of the image
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(userImage))
    {
        tempImage.Save(ms, userImage.RawFormat); //error here System.ArgumentNullException 
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I tried saving some pictures and came across with 2 images that I just can't save. They also give a "System.ArgumentNullException" even if the pictureBox has an image loaded to it.

I though it was a file size issue, but I can even save a 4 MB file(just to test). Then I saw these "attributes" in windows photo viewer and realized that maybe these "attributes" made it not savable?

An image is savable if it looks like this (its file info):

[image]

But an image is not savable if it looks like this (its file info):

[image]

**The files that were not savable was downloaded from Gmail.**

Of course I can just take a screenshot on my image and the specific attributes will just be gone and I can now save it to the database. I am just asking this because I'm just curious and I have not found any similar problem/solution about this matter. And it might be a hassle if clients will have to deal with this "screenshot" workaround.

Comment: What error is "here"?

Comment: oh sorry, I will update question.

Comment: its System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: Why are you converting userImage to a Bitmap before you Save? Why not use `Image.Save(stream, imageformat)`?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse because of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66579998/how-to-update-database-records-even-if-the-image-is-not-changed

Comment: based on your comments, I need to create a "file_extension" column in my database and also save my file extension right?